# Setting user in Upstart script for Node.JS and Forever

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, upstart

I run a web site that uses Node.JS on Ubuntu Server (14.04 LTS).  After rebooting the machine, my current workflow is to manually start the server manually by running the command

```
$ forever start app.js
```

I'm now trying to automate this process with Upstart.  I have used *chkconfig* on RHEL before, but I am new to Upstart.  I wrote the following script and saved it in */etc/init/myapp.conf*.

```
#!upstart                                                          
description "Start the node process with Upstart"         

start on startup                                                   
stop on shutdown                                                   
expect fork                                                        

env APP_DIR="/path/to/app"                         
env NODE_BIN="/usr/local/bin"                                      
env HOME_DIR="/home/admin"                                     

script                                                             
    date                                                           
    echo "Starting"                                             
    su admin                                                   
    cd $APP_DIR                                                    
    PATH=$NODE_BIN:$PATH                                           
    HOME=$HOME_DIR                                                 
    echo "Running forever start"                                   
    forever start app.js                                      
end script                                                         

pre-stop script                                                    
    date                                                           
    echo "Stopping"                                             
    su admin                                                   
    cd $APP_DIR                                                    
    PATH=$NODE_BIN:$PATH                                           
    HOME=$HOME_DIR                                                 
    echo "Running forever stop"                                    
    forever stop app.js                                       
end script
```

However, the script does not seem to work.  When I run `sudo start myapp` or `sudo stop myapp`, the console just hangs.

I would like Upstart to emulate as closely as possible to what would happen if I just signed in to the computer upon reboot and ran `forever start app.js`, including the user running the process, the default log file locations, and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

by using `upstart` you'll be able stop using `forever` for your node process management. upstart has mechanisms for ensuring your process is started/stopped/restarted in the event of a failure (or nearly any other event for that matter)

here's a modified version of your upstart script that uses upstart's `respawn` directive to handle restarting your process if it crashes:

```
description "Start the node process with Upstart"         
author "you"

# use if your process is going to fork *once*
# expect fork

# use if your process is going to fork *twice*
# exepect daemon

# respawn the process indefinitely
# (ie. disregard the number of times it crashed
# during a given interval and continuously 
# restart the process)
respawn
respawn limit unlimited

setuid admin

# ensures the process is only started once we have
# filesystem access and an ethernet interface other
# than loopback is available (ie. internet conn)
# if your node process doesn't require net connectivity
# just remove the `and net-device-up...`
start on (local-filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on shutdown

# chdir sets the directory for all script blocks 
# (pre/post/errethang)
chdir "/path/to/your/app"

script
    # we're already in /path/to/your/app cause of `chdir`                                       
    echo "app is starting"
    /usr/local/bin/node app.js 2>&1 > app.log
end script

pre-stop script
    echo "app is about to stop"
end script
```

finally, to be certain that there are no syntax errors in your service conf, you can use `init-checkconf /etc/init/myapp.conf`.

my main source of reference for upstart is [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/). this document is a bit heavyweight, though. and it's hard to discern real world usage from some of the examples.